# I am not understanding the error her in code

Tags: python-3.x, file, python-multithreading

```
import glob
from shutil import copyfile

emotions = ["neutral", "anger", "contempt", "disgust", "fear", "happy", "sadness", "surprise"] #Define emotion order
participants = glob.glob("source_emotion\\*") #Returns a list of all folders with participant numbers

for x in participants:
    part = "%s" %x[-4:] #store current participant number
    for sessions in glob.glob("%s\\*" %x): #Store list of sessions for current participant
        for files in glob.glob("%s\\*" %sessions):
            current_session = files[20:-30]
            file = open(files, 'r')

            emotion = int(float(file.readline())) #emotions are encoded as a float, readline as float, then convert to integer.

            sourcefile_emotion = glob.glob("source_images\\%s\\%s\\*" %(part, current_session))[-1] #get path for last image in sequence, which contains the emotion
            sourcefile_neutral = glob.glob("source_images\\%s\\%s\\*" %(part, current_session))[0] #do same for neutral image

            dest_neut = "sorted_set\\neutral\\%s" %sourcefile_neutral[25:] #Generate path to put neutral image
            for i in range(len(emotion)):
                dest_emot = "sorted_set\\%s\\%s" %(emotions[emotion],
                                               sourcefile_emotion[25:]) #Do same for emotion containing image

            copyfile(sourcefile_neutral, dest_neut) #Copy file
            copyfile(sourcefile_emotion, dest_emot) #Copy file
```

The above code throws an error as below:

```
runfile('K:/Facedata landmarks/data/load_images.py', wdir='K:/Facedata landmarks/data')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-0b76baf7ba54>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('K:/Facedata landmarks/data/load_images.py', wdir='K:/Facedata landmarks/data')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "K:/Facedata landmarks/data/load_images.py", line 21, in <module>
    emotion = int(float(file.readline())) #emotions are encoded as a float, readline as float, then convert to integer.

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '   9.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00\n'
```

I am reading the file data which is string but I am reading it as float and lastly converting it to int. But then also python is throwing error.Can anyone please help me solving this? I do not understand what is going wrong here and how it can be solved.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Why do you think  `'   9.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00\n'` would _automagically_ convert to `float`?

Comment: I have searched for error online. In the code at line 21 I am reading a data in sting format. And then converting it in float and then int. But why the hell string can not be converted in float and int.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: It would help if you could share the input file as well, but from the error message it appears you have multiple values per line, and your program is attempting to cast each whole input line into a single float, which would not work in this case.

Comment: What value do you expect from `float(' 9.0000000e+00 4.0000000e+00\n')`? 9? 4? 13? NaN?

Comment: I get this point and corrected it. The text file which contains 9.0000000e+00 4.0000000e+00\n should be not in one line. I have changed it as 9.0000000e+00  /n 4.0000000e+00 . and it got resolved. But now run in permission denied error. The folders are multiple and the error is coused because of last copyfile(sourcefile_neutral, dest_neut) syntax. How to solve it?